# How to create ListMenu dynamically?

Tags: android, listactivity, listadapter, expandablelistadapter

I'm working on creating a dictionary and I'm trying to create ListMenu dynamically as it is created automatically while filtering words from database alphabetically.
I created a ListMenu manually, but cannot turn it into dynamic one. Does anyone have an idea how to create the ListMenu dynamically?

Here's my code:

```
 package ge.gtug;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Settings extends ListActivity{


String listItems[] = {"AboutUs", "AboutApp", "Feedback"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Settings.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String koba = listItems[position];
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    try{
    Class myClass1 = Class.forName("ge.gtug." + koba);
    Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(Settings.this, myClass1);
    startActivity(myIntent1);
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    try {
    Class myClass2 = Class.forName("ge.gtug." + koba);
    Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(Settings.this, myClass2);
    startActivity(myIntent2);
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException o){
        o.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using an Array for storing data use a List (ArrayList, Vector, or similar). And whenever you alter the data collection you need to inform the ArrayAdapter that the data has changed - to notify the array adapter that the list has changed you call the method

```
ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Settings.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
setListAdapter(adapter);

listItems.add("new string");
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29